# keeping the newline and carriage return characters in java (groovy)

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to get command output from Linux box

eg: `tnsping`

and I want to preserve it's newline characters.

Below is the code where I add command(s) to `frows` and pass it to a function for execution

```
def oracleCommand(csm,pluginOutputs)
{
HashMap<String,String> params = IntermediateResults.get("userparams")
Map env=AppContext.get(AppCtxProperties.environmentVariables)

def fClass = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass( new File( 'plugins/infa9/Infa9CommandExecUtil.groovy' ) )
List<String> frows
frows=["tnsping $params.tns"]  //for the time being only one command is here

List<String> resultRows = fClass.newInstance().fetchCommandOutput( params, env, frows )

csm.oracleCommand(){
    oracle_input(frows[0]){}
    oracle_output(resultRows[0]){}
}
}
```

In the below code I am reading the result, splitting result based on newlines so all my newlines are gone

```
    public List<String> fetchCommandOutput( Map<String,String> params, Map env, List<String> rows )
  {

        List<String> outputRows = new ArrayList<String>()
        try
        {
            for(item in rows)
            {
                String temp=item.toString()

                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(temp);
                InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = null;

                result = new StringBuffer()
                line=null


                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result.append(line+" #10#13 ")  //Here i am trying to add the newline again, but it does not reflect in the generated xml. it just come as plain text
                }
                String tRes=result
                tRes=tRes.trim()

                outputRows.add(tRes)
                int exitVal = proc.waitFor();

            }
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

    return  outputRows
  }
```

**update**
How can i preserve my newlines or carriage returns, such that when the xml is opened with a xsl and when encountered `<pre></pre>` it should preserve its formatting?

Comment: Have you considered making your Groovy code more Groovy?  That is very much Java...I reckon you can reduce it in size quite considerably

Comment: @tim_yates: Yes you are right, but the habit of coding in java always comes in the way :)

Comment: Added an answer which makes you code more groovy, and handles the text as you wanted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I get you right, You should use `\r` and `\n`:

```
result.append(line+"\r\n");
```

or, you can get the line separator from the system:

```
result.append(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make your function more Groovy:

```
  public List<String> fetchCommandOutput( Map<String,String> params, Map env, List<String> rows )
  {
    rows.collect { item ->
      def (outtxt, errtxt) = [new StringBuffer(), new StringBuffer()].with { inbuf, errbuf ->
        def proc = item.execute()
        proc.waitForProcessOutput( inbuf, errbuf )
        [ inbuf, errbuf ]*.toString()*.trim()
      }
      if( errtxt ) {
        println "Got error $errtxt running $item"
      }
      outtxt
    }
  }
```

I believe it keeps the output in exactly the same format as the process outputs...  And you have less code to maintain...