# Passing Gstring to shell commands

Tags: groovy

I want to send a mail via Groovy. I tried with the `mail` command in mac and its working fine.

This is the command I'm using :

```
echo $message | mail -s "subject" mail@mail.com
```

Where `message` is a gstring :

```
def message = """ Hi 

 Test mail """
```

The problem I'm facing is; when the mail is delivered the `message` is coming in a single line rather than the way it stored.

Where I'm making the mistake??

Comment: How are you running that line of shell scripting?

Comment: Similar to your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049854/execute-a-command-in-linux-using-java-and-fetch-the-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
[ '/bin/bash', '-c', "echo '$msg' | mail -s 'subject' mail@mail.com" ].execute().waitFor()
```

ie: wrap the `msg` in quotes `'`

Obviously, any quotes in `msg` will need to be escaped, or this will fail.

A more resilient option would be to use java mail