# groovy ant execute with pipeTo

Tags: groovy

I am trying to use awk with pipeTo and need help with syntax.

this works:

```
def myId = 'myid'
print "ls -al".execute().pipeTo("grep ${myId}".execute()).text
```

this fails:

```
print "ls -al".execute().pipeTo('awk \'{print $2}\''.execute()).text
print "ls -al".execute().pipeTo('''awk '{print $2}' '''.execute()).text
```

Comment: Maybe try: `['awk','{print $2}'].execute()`. Separated arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [removing the space between `print` and `\$1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050055/563890):

```
p1="ls -la".execute()
p2='awk {print\$1}'.execute()
p1 | p2
p2.waitFor()
print p2.text
```

Note `p2.err.text` would contain error messages, if any (useful if `p2.text` is blank).